# Trouble installing pymssql

Tags: python, anaconda, pymssql

Trying to install pymssql with an anaconda installation and keep encountering package conflicts:

conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/prometeia pymssql

returns:

Hint: the following combinations of packages create a conflict with the remaining packages:

- python 3.4*

- pymssql

All packages are up to date (conda update --all)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that that channel doesn't have that package built for Python 3 (as you can see at https://binstar.org/prometeia/pymssql/files).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Good to know for the next time I find myself in this position.